# How to disable click event on rowChart in dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am doing a project using dc.js library. What I currently have is two nested charts:

- bar chart (above)
- rowChart (below)

[image]

I want to disable a mouse click action on the row chart, but I do want to be able to update the data if I make a different selection on the bar chart.

For now I am trying to do something like:

```
categoryChart.width(500)
    .height(300)
    .group(categoryGroup)
    .dimension(categoryDim)
    .rowsCap(10)
    .ordering(function(d) {return -d.value})
    .othersGrouper(false)
    .label(function (d) {
        return d.key;
    })
    .title(function (d) {return d.value;})
    .elasticX(true)
    .xAxis().ticks(4);
```

But I don't know what to add that can disable the click event.

Comment: Looks like you're missing xUnits on the bar chart (skinny bars). The code way to do this is `rowChart.onClick = function() {}` - pretty messy, wouldn't say it's better than the css method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can target the element(s) with css, you can simple add the css below and it will prevent any click coming from that element.

```
.chart {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[MDN pointer-events doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: That works! Thank you. However, I see it as a hack, because I am not using the library to disable/enable the mouse interactivity, I am just using an external way. It's useful though! :)

Comment: It may be a bit hackish but it works. You could probably add the css rule through javascript and add a comment so you can see it directly in the code instead of looking around in your css file.